# Множественная загрузка изображений ajax с progress-bar для каждого файла

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, progress-bar

Задача следующая: 
На сайте пользователь имеет возможность загрузить несколько файлов изображений, загрузка выполняется без перезагрузки страницы, во время загрузки появляется progressbar для каждого изображения в отдельности, когда изображения загрузились, с сервера возвращаются миниатюры изображений и располагаются ниже каждого progressbar. 
    Сейчас реализован один progressbar для всех загружаемых файлов, подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать для каждого файла по отдельности? 
html:

```
<form id="formUploadFiles" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="ajax/UploadFiles" method="POST">
```

js:

```
var bar = $('.progressbar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');
// Ajax загрузка изображений
$('#formUploadFiles').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        var inputFile = document.getElementById('upload1').files;
             var percentVal = '0%';
            //bar.show();
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);

    },
    uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal);
    },
    success: function () {          
    },
    complete: function (xhr) {
        status.append(xhr.responseText);
        //bar.hide();
        var percentVal = '100%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
        $(".deletePhoto").unbind('click');
        $(".deletePhoto").on('click', function () {
            deletePhoto($(this))
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Кто знает, нужно смотреть документацию той библиотеки, которую вы используете.

Comment: Библиотека jquery.form.js

Answer (score 1):

Так возвращайте в `AJAX'e` новую копию для загрузки файла, в чем проблема? Т.е. когда выбрали картинку, поставить туда `JS`, который делает запрос `AJAX` на создание дубликата вашей формы для выбора картинки

Comment: Не совсем поняла, что вы имеете в виду.

Answer (score 1):

[HTML5 File API](http://habrahabr.ru/post/109079/), и не надо писать кастыли

Comment: Так не во всех браузерах работать будет.

Answer (score 1):

[jquery.form.js](https://github.com/malsup/form/blob/master/jquery.form.js#L227-L258) — грузит все файлы разом через iframe или XHR2 + FormData. Событие `uploadProgress` есть только во втором случае. Так что для выполнения вашей задачи, вам нужен другой инструмент для загрузки файлов.

Comment: Я понимаю, я собственно и обратилась потому, что пока не нашла другого решения.

Comment: Для загрузки файлов есть много [хороших решений][1], например jQuery File Upload, FineUploader, Plupload и так далее.

[1]: https://www.google.ru/search?q=javascript%20file%20uploader

Comment: Мне нужна загрузка, в которой пользователь может выбрать сразу несколько файлов для загрузки.

Comment: Любое решение из перечисленных мной, дает такую возможность, пересильте себя и ознакомьтесь с ними.